# Internal Server error on jersey while posting application/xml

Tags: java, xml, jersey, postman

I've been struggling with that error for hours ; i'm trying to make an http post request with an xml in its body ; i managed to do so like this :

```
@POST
@Path("/callback")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response updateStatus(InputBean inputBean) {     
    //my code
}
```

my xml annotations are like this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @XmlElement(name ="result")
    private String result;    

    public Project() {
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult (String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }  
}
```

the input bean is actually more complex than that ; i've run my code in debug mode and verified that the inputbean is enhanced after using postman and making the request ; but there's a problem , i got some fields in my bean which has a naming like this one : project-name ; with the "-" character all those fields dont get enhanced  when making the request so i thought to add an annotation :

```
@XmlElement(name ="project-name")
    private String projectName;
```

when i add that annotation and run the code i get an internal server error 500 and can't debug the code where those values should be "readable" , i only need to enhance those fields but i still dont know how  , all the others fields without the "-" char get enhanced in the process .

xml on body request :

```
 <bag>
<action>bag­execution­result</action>
    <detail>
        <project name="IBankerPorting">
            <component>ASA</component>
            <tag>trunk//264989</tag>
            <request-id>203782</request-id>
            <tag-id>254753</tag-id>
            <date>2010-02-03 12:16</date>
            <security-needed>no</security-needed>
            <type>MAINTENANCE</type>
            <result-ci>-0.000</result-ci>
            <result-pmd-highest>-1</result-pmd-highest>
            <result-pmd-high>-1</result-pmd-high>
            <result-pmd-medium>-1</result-pmd-medium>
            <result-cc-open-issue>0</result-cc-open-issue>
            <result>approved</result>
        </project>
    </detail>
</bag>
```

ex. every field that does not contain the "-" is enhanced in my bean (has a value that has been taken by the xml thanks to jersey ) except for those with the "-" like request-id

Comment: Please clarify *is enhanced after using postman*.

Comment: Explain how `String project-name;` works in Java?

Comment: @XmlElement(name ="project-name")
private String projectName

its like that on the project , just misspelled here ; when i use postman to make the post request like http://localhost:port/etc with my xml body , the inputBean gets some values from my xml (thanks to jersey unmarshallowing property ) except the values from fields like project-name those are null ; ill update the question to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've ended up finding the solution , i added this statement in the pojo class that contained the xml fields :@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @XmlElement(name ="result")
    private String result;    

    public Project() {
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult (String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }  
}
```